# how to limit text length in a Slate editor?

Tags: reactjs, slatejs, slate-react

there must be a way to limit text length, right? — the equivalent of the `maxlength` HTML attribute on an `<input>` or `<textarea>`

what I tried? . I tried using `onDOMBeforeInput` to test the length, but found that if I paste something in, that handler wasn’t called . anyway, there must be a simple way, right? . what am I missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.